# Qn: Is apt (on the Mac) the same as apt-get?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, command-line, apt-get

I'm a little new to this so pardon me.

I am following a book which requires me to do "sudo apt-get install..." on an Ubuntu OS, but I only have a Mac. Found a UNIX executable in my Mac installed by default named "apt". I assume "apt" was the same as "apt-get", but when I typed in the relevant commands I get:

```
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

OR (when I split "apt" and "-get" with a space)

```
apt: invalid flag: -get
Usage: apt <apt and javac options> <source files>
where apt options include:
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processor factories
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processor factories
  -d <path>                  Specify where to place processor and javac generated class files
  -s <path>                  Specify where to place processor generated source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options; use javac -help for more options
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  -A[key[=value]]            Options to pass to annotation processors
  -nocompile                 Do not compile source files to class files
  -print                     Print out textual representation of specified types
  -factorypath <path>        Specify where to find annotation processor factories
  -factory <class>           Name of AnnotationProcessorFactory to use; bypasses default discovery process
See javac -help for information on javac options.
```

Is apt and apt-get the same thing?

I am trying to install python3-minimal, and other digital forensic tools.

P.S.
This question does relate to: [What's the equivalent of Ubuntu's apt-get command on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/553546/whats-the-equivalent-of-ubuntus-apt-get-command-on-a-mac) and [What is the difference between Linux (Ubuntu) and Mac shell commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/315601/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-ubuntu-and-mac-shell-commands), but those posts don't deal directly with the fact that there is an apt UNIX executable on the Mac.

Comment: If you want a good package manager for OS X, try [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two unrelated commands. If you run `man apt` on your Mac, it appears to be a tool for Java development. From the `man` page:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The tool apt, annotation processing tool, includes a set of new reflective APIs and supporting infrastructure to process program annotations. The apt reflective APIs provide  a  build-time, source-based, read-only view of program structure. These reflective APIs are designed to cleanly model the JavaTM programming language's type system after the addition of generics.

`man`, however, is the same tool on both platforms, so it's a useful resource regardless of your knowledge level. Running `man <command>` will display help associated with that command.